# Converting a list into XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, arrays, object

For a project I'm currently working on, I'm given an array of objects, each of which contain a "content" property and a "level" property.  I need to convert this list into an HTML bulleted list.  For example, if I was given the following input (shown in JSON for simplicity):

```
[ {content: "Hey", level: "1"},
  {content: "I just met you", level: "2"},
  {content: "and this is crazy", level: "2"},
  {content: "but here's my number", level: "1"},
  {content: "call me, maybe", level: "3"} ]
```

I would need to convert it to the following XHTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>I just met you</li>
      <li>and this is crazy</li>          
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>but here's my number</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>call me, maybe</li>      
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The end product would look like this:

- Hey

  - I just met you
  - and this is crazy
- but here's my number

  - call me, maybe (**<- one level deeper** - I don't think I can do this in SO)

Kind of a weird puzzle.  Any suggestions as to an algorithm/approach that would be most efficient/easy to implement?  I'm implementing this in C#, but an example/idea in another language would be more than welcome.

Comment: It is very hard for me to not down vote for using call me maybe lyrics. :)

Comment: Do you want HTML or XML?

Comment: @jrummell: I'll want HTML eventually, but if there's a way to produce it using XML techniques, I'm sure I can build it that was as well.

Comment: Start by looking at the C# class [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (since you posted this under C#). Linked there is the Microsoft documentation for it. Additionally, a simple Google search will turn up plenty of examples on how to do this. [Here's one](http://forums.asp.net/t/1407620.aspx/1)

Comment: @DougRamsey You're only about 100 rep away from being able to repla ... I mean, *edit*, the lyrics. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that as long as the level is greater than or equal to the previous, it should be nested, and if it is lesser, than it should be closed.

```
public string BuildLists(List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pairs)
{
    int CurrentLevel = 1;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    s.Append("<ul>");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in pairs)
    {
        if(pair.Value > CurrentLevel)
        {
            //Nest more
            for(int i = 0; i < pair.Value - CurrentLevel; i++)
            {
                s.Append("<li><ul>");
            }
        }
        else if(pair.Value < CurrentLevel)
        {
            //Close Tags
            for(int i = 0; i < CurrentLevel - pair.Value; i++)
            {
                s.Append("</ul></li>");
            }
        }

        s.Append("<li>" + pair.Key + "</li>");

        CurrentLevel = pair.Value
    }

    //Close everything.
    for(int i = 0; i < CurrentLevel - 1; i++)
    {
        s.Append("</ul></li>");
    }

    s.Append("</ul>");
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess that the person who did, did it because your solution is missing to close some tags. It produces the following output: `<ul><li>Hey</li><li><ul><li>I just met you</li><li>and this is crazy</li></li></
ul><li>but here's my number</li><li><ul><li><ul><li>call me, maybe</li></ul>` which is not what the OP wants and is invalid as you haven't closed your `<ul>`s. Did you test your code for the given input?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I forgot to swap the order of the close tags. Edited.

Comment: +1 for a solid idea.  I think I can work off this.  Like Darin Dimitrox mentioned, it's not quite producing the correct output, but it's given me a lead to pursue.